# Printing a ticket in xpages

Tags: printing, xpages, openoffice-writer

In a xpages application I need to mount a label with a certain layout, analogous to the layout of a ticket. Searching, I have verified that the most used practice is to use openoffice to design the odt model and in java to use bilbiotec to JOD Reports. Do you advise to follow this line yourself, or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I would have a look at Apache Fop to create a pdf based on a template. It gives you the possibility to define the size of the pdf. If needed there is also a plugin to add  barcodes to the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I would concur with Marcus. The way forward is PDF output. There are a couple of ways to do this, depending on your constraints.

- When user must design every aspect of the ticket using openoffice is a suitable approach, however you need a headless openoffice install for the rendering
- If everything can be code, then [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) is a good way to go. Wrap your code into a managed bean
- The middle path would be XSL:FO and Apache FOP. It allows alteration of the layout by providing a different style sheet. I wrote an [article series](https://wissel.net/blog/2012/04/extracting-data-from-domino-into-pdf-using-xslt-and-xslfo-part-1.html) outlining that approach.

Let us know what works for you!

Answer (score 0):

There is also the POI4XPages plugin. You could design your form with Word and then use placeholders to populate the document and output as a pdf.
See https://poi4xpages.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/POI%204%20XPages/releases/E80C4FC9FB07E1E4852580E3006E02C7

Download the latest version (1.4) at http://p2.openntf.org/repository.nsf/home.xsp/poi4xpages/snapshots

Howard

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem, because I discovered that here in the company there is the abcpdf software. Through a web service that uses the APis of this software, I pass the html code of the ticket and the web service returns the pdf document in an array of bytes. I created a managed javabean to consume the web service and display the pdf in the browser.

Thanks to all who have contributed in some way with suggestions.